# Edittext background color issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a linear layout with two child items, an edittext fied and button. I set the background color of the linear layout to a shade of blue. On android api 8 the the edittext field has a white background which is how i want it to be, however on android api 17+ the edittext background is the same as the linear layout and thus makes the text input a little difficult to read since it is black.

When i change the edittext background to white (#ffffff) from the default value "?android:attr/editTextBackground", the height of the edittext becomes smaller and doesn't maintain its previous look. My question is how can i maintain the edittext's background as white without altering other attributes that are effected by "?android:attr/editTextBackground" throughout all api levels?

And also i failed to figure out which file the attribute "?android:attr/editTextBackground" points to so i could perhaps look there and edit. Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/search_layout_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:shadowColor="#77000000"
        android:shadowDx="-2.4"
        android:shadowDy="2.4"
        android:shadowRadius="1.2" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint_search"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_textSize" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/search"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give the height to the edittext

Comment: I was hopping i could find a solution to surround the edittext with my custom color without having to change its parameters like it appears on android api 8. Thanks for your contribution though.